# Populate array inside object in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a company model which looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CompanySchema = new Schema(
  {
    companyName: String,
    settings: {
      type: {
        priceVisible: Boolean,
        allowPickupAddressAddition: Boolean,
        paymentMethodsAvailable: [
          { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "PaymentMethod" },
        ],
      },
    },    
  }
);

const Company = mongoose.model("Company", CompanySchema);

module.exports = Company;
```

And I want to populate the values store in `paymentMethodsAvailable` array. Here is relevant controller code:

```
const company = await Company.findOne({ _id: id }).populate([
      {
        path: "settings",
        populate: [{path: "paymentMethodsAvailable"}]
      },
    ]);
```

But this doesn't work as expected. I can see that it might be trying to populate settings object, and fails there. Is there a way in which I can tell mongoose to populate `settings.paymentMethodsAvailable` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should notice [The `type` Key](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#type-key):

> `type` is a special property in Mongoose schemas. When Mongoose finds a nested property named type in your schema, Mongoose assumes that it needs to define a `SchemaType` with the given type.

- If the `type` is a nested property of `settings`, the Mongoose schema should be:

```
const CompanySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    companyName: String,
    settings: {
        type: {
            type: {
                priceVisible: Boolean,
                paymentMethodsAvailable: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'PaymentMethod' }],
            },
        },
    },
});

// seed
const [p1] = await PaymentMethod.create([{ name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }]);
const [c1] = await Company.create([
  {
    companyName: 'c-a',
    settings: {
      type: {
        priceVisible: true,
        paymentMethodsAvailable: [p1],
      },
    },
  },
]);

// populate
const company = await Company.findOne({ _id: c1?._id }).populate('settings.type.paymentMethodsAvailable');
console.log(util.inspect(company?.toObject(), false, null));
```

The populate path is `settings.type.paymentMethodsAvailable`.

Output:

```
{
  settings: {
    type: {
      priceVisible: true,
      paymentMethodsAvailable: [
        {
          _id: new ObjectId("64abce807233874fe5733d10"),
          name: 'a',
          __v: 0
        }
      ],
      _id: new ObjectId("64abce807233874fe5733d15")
    }
  },
  _id: new ObjectId("64abce807233874fe5733d14"),
  companyName: 'c-a',
  __v: 0
}
```

- If the `type` is **not** a nested property of `settings`, the Mongoose schema is like yours:

```
const CompanySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    companyName: String,
    settings: {
        type: {
            priceVisible: Boolean,
            paymentMethodsAvailable: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'PaymentMethod' }],
        },
    },
});

// seed
const [p1] = await PaymentMethod.create([{ name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }]);
const [c1] = await Company.create([
  {
    companyName: 'c-a',
    settings: {
      priceVisible: true,
      paymentMethodsAvailable: [p1],
    },
  },
]);

// populate
const company = await Company.findOne({ _id: c1?._id }).populate('settings.paymentMethodsAvailable');
console.log(util.inspect(company?.toObject(), false, null));
```

The populate path is `settings.paymentMethodsAvailable`.

Output:

```bash
{
  _id: new ObjectId("64abd00acd28f4120a317c2e"),
  companyName: 'c-a',
  settings: {
    priceVisible: true,
    paymentMethodsAvailable: [
      {
        _id: new ObjectId("64abd00acd28f4120a317c2a"),
        name: 'a',
        __v: 0
      }
    ],
    _id: new ObjectId("64abd00acd28f4120a317c2f")
  },
  __v: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const company = await Company.findOne({ _id: id }).populate(
    "settings.paymentMethodsAvailable"
);
```

You can find more examples in the documentation. I was using this section as a reference https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populating-maps

Comment: This returns null value

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose provides clear syntax
The following code will work fine

```
const company = await Company.findOne({ _id: id }).populate(
    "settings.type.paymentMethodsAvailable"
);

if(!company) {
    // if there is no company with that id
    // this acully not error it's simply
    // return `null` to tell you company not found.
    res.status(404).send()
}
```

Also: you can go further and populate specific fields inside `settings.paymentMethodsAvailable`

```
const company = await Company.findOne({ _id: id }).populate(
    "settings.type.paymentMethodsAvailable",
    "field1 filed2 filed3"
);
```

Comment: tried this as the first thing, this returns null.

Comment: I edit it, try now